# How to move a customized Tikz command around a page

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a custom command which builds me a pretty picture (the custom replaces 5 draw commands) and I want to be able to copy and move this picture around my document. This is so that I can save myself time and get identical/symetrical drawings for my doc. The problem  I am having is that now that I have built my custom command, I cannot move it around my page. The latest monstrosity I've built follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\let\svtikzpicture\tikzpicture
\def\tikzpicture{\noindent\svtikzpicture}

\newcommand{\branchUp}[2][]{
    \tikz{
           \node[fill=black,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3,inner sep=1] at (#1 + 0.25,#2+3) {}; \\
    \draw(#1 + 0.25,#2 + 0) -- (#1 + 0.25,#2 + 3);     \\
    \draw(#1 + 0.25,#2 + 1.1) circle(0.2);   \\
    \draw(#1 + 0.25,#2 + 0.9) circle(0.2);   \\
    \draw [thick] (#1 +0,#2 + 2) -- (#1 + 0.5,#2 + 2); \\
    }}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5];

\branchUp (1,1);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

All I really want to do it write something like:

```
\branchUp at (1,1)
```

and have it populate my figure properly orientated at (1,1). Right now I am doing this manually and it's not fun when I have to change something and make 12+ edits to see what a slight adjust looks like.

Thanks for any help, I've not had good luck finding documentation that doesn't confuse me on \newcommand implementation.

Comment: You are nesting `tikzpicture`s, which is not supported but dangerous. Use a `pic` instead. This can be placed wherever you like.

Comment: The LaTeX tutorial on Overleaf builds a circuit the same way I am trying to build my one-line. The difference is I have to create my own special nodes (there isn't a OneLine package that I know of, yet). Are you suggesting the Overleaf Tutorial is wrong, these two types of drawings are different, or something else? It seems to me like I am just trying to build my own special nodes and I don't know how to.

Comment: If the Overleaf tutorial nests `tikzpicture`s, it is wrong.

Comment: Could you link to the overleaf tutorial please?

Comment: I should note that they are using a defined library for their circuit stuff and I was trying to define a shape to use in my circuit and initialized it outside the loop (hence abcdefg saying I did it wrong). Knowing what I know now, I don't think the overleaf tutorial was wrong: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/LaTeX_Graphics_using_TikZ:_A_Tutorial_for_Beginners_(Part_4)%E2%80%94Circuit_Diagrams_Using_Circuitikz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the sort of thing that `pic`s were designed for.  Using a pic, one can squirrel away a set of drawing commands to be used together and reuse them frequently.  It also handles positioning itself so you don't need to.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\let\svtikzpicture\tikzpicture
\def\tikzpicture{\noindent\svtikzpicture}

\tikzset{
  branchUp/.pic={
     \node[fill=black,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3,inner sep=1] at ( 0.25,3) {}; 
    \draw(0.25,0) -- ( 0.25, 3);  
    \draw( 0.25,1.1) circle(0.2);  
    \draw( 0.25,0.9) circle(0.2);  
    \draw [thick] (0,2) -- ( 0.5, 2);
}
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5];

\fill[red] (1,1) circle[radius=3pt];
\pic at (1,1) {branchUp};


\fill[green] (3,-1) circle[radius=3pt];
\pic at (3,-1) {branchUp};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Produces

[image: example from question converted to a pic]

The TikZ/PGF manual is quite lengthy, but now that you know about pics you should be able to find plenty of examples in there using them.

(I didn't change this in your code, but the arrow tip could be achieved using an arrow from the `arrows.meta` library)

Answer (score 2):

After abcdefg's response, I learned:

```
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5];

\newcommand{\branchUp}[2]{
           \node[fill=black,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3,inner sep=1] at (#1 + 0.25,#2+3) {}; \\
    \draw(#1 + 0.25,#2 + 0) -- (#1 + 0.25,#2 + 3);     \\
    \draw(#1 + 0.25,#2 + 1.1) circle(0.2);   \\
    \draw(#1 + 0.25,#2 + 0.9) circle(0.2);   \\
    \draw [thick] (#1 +0,#2 + 2) -- (#1 + 0.5,#2 + 2); \\
    }

\branchUp {0}{6};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

does what I want it too exactly, and solves the nested issue abcdefg brought up!

The '[2][]' in my command declaration was causing my x value to always be 0.

Comment: This resolves the nesting problem. Probably you want to add `\path (0,0);` to the contents of your macro, otherwise the overall shift just gets absorbed in a redefinition/shift of the bounding box.

Comment: You can define the macro outside a tikz environment, so long as you don't expand it there.  Right now it is local to the tikzpicture (unless you use `\global\let\branchup=\branchup`).